# Check URL/IP with port

Tags: java, regex, url

My Java 11/Android app has to check if the URL/IP the user entered could theoretically be valid (using `myURL.trim().matches(regex)`).

What should be valid (including variations):

- stackoverflow.com
- http://stackoverflow.com
- http://amazon.co.uk
- https://www.amazon.co.uk
- ftp://10.1.1.9
- 10.1.1.9:1234
- http://10.1.1.9:1234/bla

What shouldn't be valid:

- http://bla
- bla
- "---" (without the "", had to add them because of formatting)
- 10.9
- 10.1.1.
- 10.1..1.9

I don't care if the user enters e.g. "999.999.999.999", I only want to know if the syntax is theoretically correct, which it would be in this case.

So far I've been using this regex:

```
String regex1 = "((http|https|ftp)://)?((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
```

... but now I want to check for the port too and ^ doesn't support that. This other version supports ports:

```
String regex2 = "((http|https|ftp)://)?(([^/:.[:space:]]+(.[^/:.[:space:]]+)*)|([0-9](.[0-9]{3})))(:[0-9]+)?((/[^?#[:space:]]+)([^#[:space:]]+)?(#.+)?)?";
```

... but it returns `true` for strings like "http://bla" or "---".

I also tested [this version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff650303(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) by Microsoft:

```
String regex3 = "^(ht|f)tp(s?)\\:\\/\\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.\\?\\,\\'\\/\\\\\\+&amp;%\\$#_]*)?$";
```

... but it doesn't work for some of the above examples ("http://bla" and "http://10.1.1.9:1234/bla" are valid, "10.1.1.9" and "stackoverflow.com" aren't) and I'm not sure how to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015516/2016165) long PHP version to work with java, as it complains about the "#" and ")".

I'm aware there's already a lot of regex code for validating URLs floating around on stackoverflow and I already tested a bunch of other versions from the [mega-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/2016165) (and other questions) but the ones that I could get Android Studio to accept didn't work and my regex "knowledge" isn't even remotely big enough to modify someone else's code, let alone write my own.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: does it have to use regex or we could leverage [URL class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)?

Comment: You'll find it a lot easier to simply try to connect to it than validate it lexically

Comment: @BagusTesa I want to check the URL without having to establish an internet connection. It doesn't have to be perfect and I don't need checks for wrong things like IPs > 255. I'll try to connect to the actual URL later (have to do a lot of other stuff first) but I don't want to let the user get that far in the first place if they enter something that's completely wrong syntax-wise (like "10.9" or "http://bla"), so I can minimize the amount of timeouts.

Comment: You probably don't need to worry about timeouts. Set the timeout to a value the user won't notice

Comment: @anubhava A while ago (Java 7 or Java 8) I tested both `URL` and `URI` but the former always asked for a prefix (so e.g. "stackoverflow.com" wouldn't work) and URI was fine with even "---". No idea if that's still the same.

Comment: @g00se The server my app's going to connect to and use later can be slow sometimes, so I have to give it enough time to actually respond. The timeout's currently set to 10s and I'd rather not have the user wait 10s every time if I can do a regex check instead that's a lot quicker.

Comment: @Neph does [this](https://regex101.com/r/aRi65l/1) works for you? tbh, validating URLs and covers every single url conceivable is an [act of madness](https://xkcd.com/1726/). some argue `http://bla` is a valid url - try adding `bla` on your `hosts` list and point it to local server, the (c)TLD is totally optional.

Comment: @BagusTesa Interesting. That won't be necessary in my case, neither will e.g. "localhost:1234". I'm aware you can't cover every basis with regex, that's why I'm only testing it with the very basics that I know are going to come up at one point. Thanks, testing it now.

Comment: while at it `http://amazon.co.uk/some-path?name=value`, and a wholeset of url (and) escaped entities..

Comment: @anubhava Ahm, tbh, I don't care. For now there aren't going to be any "?" or "=" in the URL the user has to enter.

Comment: [Check if this regex](https://regex101.com/r/DGFT26/1) works for you

Comment: @BagusTesa Just finished testing it and it's perfect, it even works with e.g. "http://10.1.1.9:1234/bla/cats/more/alsodogs/". Thanks! Edit: Going to test your update on Monday.

Comment: @Neph [updated](https://regex101.com/r/aRi65l/4), now it verifies that no ip address looking like `300.300.300.300`, still stupidly allows `299` though. it also validates querystring somewhat. i'll be cursed for making this.

Comment: @anubhava Just finished testing your solution and it works perfectly with the examples above and a couple of extras in my code, thanks! I think I'll go with Bagus' solution because it also checks the IP and port for the correct length, which I didn't ask for in my question but could still be useful. Want to post your code as an answer too?

Comment: @Neph: Accepted answer doesn't validate `https://x.com` which is a valid domain

Comment: @anubhava Ah, that special case, you're correct, I didn't think of `t.co` either. There are far [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-letter_second-level_domain) of those in use than expected, even non-ascii ones but that would be completely overkill (and the URLs I have to validate are not going to be single-letter). Going to test your updated version tomorrow, thanks. What makes your solution "far more efficient"? Is it just about the length of the regex code?

Comment: No regex length is never a criteria. On regex101 site click on a flavor (such as Python that shows number of steps taken to execute) and you will see a big difference in steps count between my answer and his. Septs count is shown at top right of the regex text area.

Comment: @anubhava I just tested the new version and it works as well as your first one with my test URLs, thanks! It's weird, the website only shows the steps for "v1" of your code, for the second one and Bagus' solution it doesn't, instead it displays the time it took to find the matches and even that fluctuates heavily: With about 30 test strings there might be a difference of just 1-2ms one time and the next it's 10ms.

Comment: Bagus's regex is this: https://regex101.com/r/aRi65l/4 Once you open it, you need to click on `Python` under `FLAVOR` menu to get steps taken. Once I do that it shows  2575 steps.

Comment: @anubhava Ah, I used Java, not Python, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to lose this regex in case I need it in the future so I will put it here.

The regex below separated into schema, subdomain(s), domain, (c)TLD, separate handling for IPv4 Address*, URL paths, query string, and finally anchor.

```
^(((ht|f)tps?)://)?(((\w+\-*\w+\.)*(\w+\-*\w+)(\.[\w]{2,})+)|(((1|2){0,1}[0-9]{1,2}\.){3}(1|2){0,1}[0-9]{1,2}))(:[0-9]{2,5})?(/(#/)?[\w0-9+\/\-]*(\?([\w0-9 ]+=([\w0-9]|%[0-7][0-9a-f])+&?)*)?(#[\w0-9]*)?)*$
```

It will see the following as valid URL:

```
stackoverflow.com
http://stackoverflow.com
http://stack-overflow.com
http://test-1.stack-overflow.com/salsa1/#11223a
http://salsa.com/#/about-us
http://test.com/#/about--cats
http://amazon.co.uk
https://www.amazon.co.uk
ftp://10.1.1.9
10.1.1.9:1234/bla/bla/bla
255.1.1.9/bla/bla/bla
http://10.1.1.9:1234/bla/bla
http://amazon.co.uk/?name=value
http://amazon.co.uk/test?name=value&sasa=1
http://amazon10.com
```

There might be many things it does not cover, but perhaps someone else can write better regex.

* The IP Address still allows 299, but it disallow 300 and above.

Fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/aRi65l/4

Comment: What about IPv6 :D?

Comment: @khachik oh right :(

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to answer with one enhancement. You may use this *optimized* regex:

```bash
^(?:(?:ht|f)tps?://)?(?=(?:\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4}){3}|[^:/\n]*[^:/.\d\n])(?:[:/]|$))[\da-z](?!\w*-[/.?])[\w-]*(?:\.[-\w]*[\da-z])+(?::\d+)?(?:/[-\w.?\,'/\\\+&;%\$#?&=]*)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DGFT26/4)

Comment: What did you change with the edit?

Comment: It is a small enhancement in negative lookahead i.e. `(?!\w*-[/.?])` to make `http://stack-overflow.com` valid.

Answer (score 1):

**This maybe the most complete regex for checking whether an URL valid**

```
^(((ht|f)(tp)(s)?(:\/\/))?(([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))(:\d{1,5})?((\/)([\w\.~%-]+))*(\/)?((\?)(([\w]+)(=[\w\.~%-])?((&)([\w]+)(=[\w\.~%-])?)*)?)?((#)((([\w]+(=[\w\,\*\.~%-]+)?)(&[\w]+(=[\w\,\*\.~%-]+)?)*)|(:~:text=([\w\.~%-]+\,)?([\w\.~%-]+)(\,[\w\.~%-]+){0,2}))?)?)$
```

**1st part: Scheme**

> - http ://
> - https://
> - ftp ://
> - ftps://

```
((ht|f)(tp)(s)?(:\/\/))?
```

**2nd part: domain or IPv4 address**

> - 192.168.0.1
> - stackoverflow.com

```
(([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))
```

**3rd part: port**

> - :65535
> - :1

```
(:\d{1,5})?
```

**4th part: path**

> - /edu/
> - /about
> - /acc/user/management

```
((\/)([\w\.~%-]+))*(\/)?
```

**5th part: query**

> - ?query=a&b=c

```
((\?)(([\w]+)(=[\w\.~%-]+)?((&)([\w]+)(=[\w\.~%-]+)?)*)?)?
```

**6th part: Fragments**

> - #about
> - #line=10,20
> - #row=5-7
> - #row=5-*
> - #cell=4,1-6,2
> - #t=40,80&xywh=160,120,320,240
> - #:~:text=prefix-,textStart,textEnd,-suffix

```
^(((ht|f)(tp)(s)?(:\/\/))?(([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))(:\d{1,5})?((\/)([\w\.~%-]+))*(\/)?((\?)(([\w]+)(=[\w\.~%-]+)?((&)([\w]+)(=[\w\.~%-]+)?)*)?)?((#)((([\w]+(=[\w\,\*\.~%-]+)?)(&[\w]+(=[\w\,\*\.~%-]+)?)*)|(:~:text=([\w\.~%-]+\,)?([\w\.~%-]+)(\,[\w\.~%-]+){0,2}))?)?)$
```

Comment: Please do not use your own website as an example or hidden promotion.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here is the relevant *[ABNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)* from, *[RFC 1738 – Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738)*.

```
genericurl     = scheme ":" schemepart
scheme         = 1*[ lowalpha | digit | "+" | "-" | "." ]
schemepart     = *xchar | ip-schemepart
ip-schemepart  = "//" login [ "/" urlpath ]
login          = [ user [ ":" password ] "@" ] hostport
user           = *[ uchar | ";" | "?" | "&" | "=" ]
password       = *[ uchar | ";" | "?" | "&" | "=" ]
hostport       = host [ ":" port ]
host           = hostname | hostnumber
hostname       = *[ domainlabel "." ] toplabel
hostnumber     = digits "." digits "." digits "." digits
domainlabel    = alphadigit | alphadigit *[ alphadigit | "-" ] 
toplabel       = alpha | alpha *[ alphadigit | "-" ] alphadigit
port           = digits
urlpath        = *xchar    ; depends on protocol see section 3.1
uchar          = unreserved | escape
xchar          = unreserved | reserved | escape
unreserved     = alpha | digit | safe | extra
safe           = "$" | "-" | "_" | "." | "+"
extra          = "!" | "*" | "'" | "(" | ")" | ","
reserved       = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "="
escape         = "%" hex hex
```

Comment: How does this help answer my question?